# My visual basic program is creating files improperly and they won't run correctly through other programs

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, automation, hex, vb.net-2010

I have a visual basic program that creates files that are necessary for a semiweekly process. These files are a .bas file (for qbasic) and a .lot file (for voxco automation). I can live without the .bas file and simply put it's functionality directly into my program. I do, however, need the .lot file. Normally these files are copied from old files and edited manually. This is, as you can imagine, tedious.  However, the files created by my program do not run properly through any means I have of running them. When I compare the manually created files to the automatically created files, the differences are minimal to nonexistent. The encoding doesn't seem to be an issue either. I simply don't know why the files created by my program are not running properly when the files created manually are working fine.

Here is the code that creates the .lot file:

```
Dim LotText As String
LotText = *removed*
Dim QuLines As String = Nothing
Dim Reader As New StreamReader(LotFilePath & OldStudy & ".LOT")
Dim SLine As String = Nothing
While Not Reader.EndOfStream
    SLine = Reader.ReadLine()
    If SLine.StartsWith("*QU") Then
        QuLines = QuLines & SLine & vbCrLf
    End If
End While
LotText = LotText & QuLines

Dim TempPath As String
TempPath = LotFilePath & "BackEnd\" & StudyID & ".LOT"
My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText(TempPath, LotText, 0)
```

Comment: How would you expect us to help with so few info ? I would suggest to compare the proper files and the wrong ones for a start...

Comment: Apologies. I tried to put the hex codes up but couldn't do it in a readable way. It's also a little difficult to put things up in a way such that all sensitive info is removed.

Answer (score 0):

When you say the differences are minimal - what are they exactly!?  A single character at the beginning of the file could be making the whole thing fail.

I have had problems in the past with writing vbCrLf to files in this manner; try the following code instead to see if it offers any improvement.

```
Dim LotText As String = *removed*
' Create a list of strings for the output data
Dim QuLines As New Collections.Generic.List(Of String)
Dim Reader As New StreamReader(Path.Combine(LotFilePath, OldStudy & ".LOT"))
Dim SLine As String = Nothing
While Not Reader.EndOfStream
    SLine = Reader.ReadLine()
    If SLine.StartsWith("*QU") Then
        ' This line is desired; add it to our output list
        QuLines.Add(SLine)
    End If
End While
' Concatenate the existing data and the output; uses the system defined NewLine
LotText &= Environment.NewLine & String.Join(Environment.Newline, QuLines)

Dim TempPath As String = Path.Combine(LotFilePath, "BackEnd", StudyID & ".LOT")
My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText(TempPath, LotText, 0)
```

Comment: One of the files I made had a difference of a space at the end of a line (which was not present in the text) and another had no difference. It was difficult to tell if changing that extra space had any effect because when I saved it the hex editor made it difficult to run the file (it put some sort of protection on the file). The .Add method doesn't seem to work in my program - I get an error that the .Add method is not a member of the String object. I tried changing all the vbcrlf's to vblf's, but that has not helped.

Comment: OK, having edited the files so that they are identical in the hex code, the program still will not run the files properly. I've had my vb.net program stop putting in a byte order mark and use proper encoding, but it still is finding something wrong. IO'm not getting an error, but the program will open and than close immediately, as though the file loaded into it is blank.

Comment: The .Add method is not a member of String, no.  It is a member of List(Of String) though - please read ALL the changes I made to your code!  I will edit the post to add further comments (sorry, I was in a rush earlier).  You may have to post your hex file findings too - it's a bit hard to guess what's going on.

Comment: I changed my code to match yours and get one error - "Expression does not produce a value" for the expression "Qulines.Add(Sline)"

Comment: The error was me neglecting to delete the preceding "QuLines = ". But now that this works, the output is entirely blank. filesize = 0bytes

Comment: HELLO! OK, I've found a couple of things that i overlooked: 1, the temppath was missing a \ after backend so thats why the final file was empty. 2, the example study I'd been using for the last hour was one that doesn't even exist yet in the sql database! Damnit! So, your snippet works, and I'm not entirely sure whether or not i had actually fixed it earlier by changing the encoding. But oh well, at least things are working now!

Comment: Hopefully you can get back to diagnosing the problem now then!  There shouldn't have been a backslash missing - `Path.Combine` should have concatenated all your path elements.  It might help with small routines like this if you use breakpoints and step through your code to see exactly what it's doing.